# find last position of char in string in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to copy rows, but I also need, to change `path` field:

old `path` value = `'<src_dir>'/workspace_id/project_id/file_id.file_format`

new `path` value = `'<src_dir>'/workspace_id/new_project_id/new_file_id.file_format`

I tried to find the dot position and count from it two uuid lengths + slash and put there new slash-separated project and file IDs

```
overlay(path, placing '{<new_project_id>}/{<new_file_id>}' from (position('.' in path)-(36 * 2 + 1) for (36 * 2 + 1)))
```

But if a `src_dir` contains a dot in its name, the position of that dot will be taken. Is there any way to take the position of the last dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REVERSE()` function along with `LENGTH()` such as

```sql
SELECT LENGTH(path) - POSITION( '.' IN REVERSE(path)) + 1
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5e63219479ee8e3f8bb5c1cec180891d)</kbd>

this case the last dot would be positioned as the first

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not pro in regexp, it can it could be much prettier, but it works:

```
regexp_replace(path, '([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\/(([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\.)', '{new_project_id}/{new_file_id}.')
```